# Page style display correctly in IE, Chrome, Opera but doesn't in Firefox

Tags: firefox, twitter-bootstrap, styles

Page style display correctly in IE, Chrome, Opera but does not in Firefox. I don't know how to fix it, please help me.
This is my **css** files:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?     family=Aclonica:regular">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrapBase.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stilearn.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stilearn-responsive.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stilearn-helper.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stilearn-icon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/uniform.default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/uniform.default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/datepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/responsive-tables.css">
```

Comment: Add your code here and also help us to understand what is the exact issue you are facing. A screenshot or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would help. Right now it's difficult to understand the problem.

Comment: ok, I'll add screenshot.

Comment: This is a normal http://screencast.com/t/VSlBhZhnqbxv.                  This is a Firfox version  http://screencast.com/t/wmaXm9tOVXg

Comment: Ok, can you also paste the code to your question?

Comment: I can add only css files, my codes are many large.

Comment: Can you temporarily host on some FTP?

Comment: No, @Nathan Lee. I can't.

Comment: I think that it is problem of Firefox, but few days agoI saw this issue, and It was displayed because I copy some of jQuery code from other js file to mine, When I add this js file to my root, the problem fixed.